# BTC multisig wallet with rekeying

Tags: multi-signature, schnorr-signatures, musig

I'm trying to create a Bitcoin multisig wallet. At this point, the wallet must meet the following conditions

1. must be capable of k-of-n threshold signatures (schnorr, musig, etc.)
2. it should be possible to change the internal key **without changing the wallet address.**

The signing process can be observed on-chain, or it can look like a single transaction.
Is it possible to create a wallet like the above? I've searched for several days and couldn't get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MuSig can only be used for k-of-k setups. For k-of-n you need a different protocol such as FROST or ROAST. It is possible to create a new quorum of n from k keys, I am aware that Bitkey described such a scheme for their pending Taproot-based setup, but as far as I am aware nobody has fully described a protocol to implement a rekeying process yet.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. 
Please understand that I don't have much experience with blockchain, so there was some confusion in my use of terminology. My goal is to implement a k-of-n threshold signature wallet as you pointed out.

Regarding the idea of creating a new quorum that overrides n with only k keys, can you provide me with any resources or explanation of the concept, even if it's not a direct implementation?

P.S. I was looking for you when I saw you answered this on another forum xD

Comment: @dohyeon.eth I think your searches may be stifled by the fact that at this point, this is research-level stuff. There is progress, but there are no (or almost no) production quality software available for consumers at this point.

Comment: Thank you for all guys. This is going to be a tough challenge for me.